# Print composer messes up layout of different maps

Tags: qgis, print-composer, printing

I made a map including 3 levels of zoom as shown in the screenshot. The problem is that whenever I save the map to a PDF, the layout of these maps is changed seemingly random. [image: In the lower left image, the purple region appears in the sea]

[image: This is how the map is supposed to look. Only difference is I saved the file another name. Usually, the image becomes even more distorted, but hopefully you get the idea.]

I have a hunch that it has to do something with 'Lock layers' or 'Lock styles for layers' functions, but they don't really seem to work. Right now, I have the lock layers box checked on all maps and Lock styles for layers unchecked.

Comment: OpenLayers plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to start from the first map by activating the layers you want to make visibile; once this is done, check **Lock layer** and **Lock styles for layers** option and then pass to the next map. Finally, try using the **Refresh** button before saving to PDF, so you can see the map being saved:

[image]

Or maybe, as @Nathan W correctly says, it could be due to the using of the **OpenLayers** plugin: try using **QuickMapServices** plugin instead of it.

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem was indeed the OpenLayers plugin!